# What is the best way to check for the new Roblox topbar?

Tags: lua, roblox

Many games have topbar-relying GUIs, and some of them are messed up with this new topbar update. This could be very useful for lots of games (like Bloxburg) and other scripts (like HD Admin which uses a topbar icon.) As of right now, these games and scripts look like this:
[image: HD Admin]
Wow, this one actually looks okay! But there isn't icon consistency. And now, Bloxburg:
[image: Bloxburg]
This one needs a major improvement. Take a look at the Chat and Menu icons, they're offset. Coeptus could definitely use a function to fix this. So anyway, what is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the best way to check for the new Roblox topbar:

```lua
local Player = game:GetService("Players").LocalPlayer
local s, f = pcall(function()
    Player.PlayerGui:SetTopbarTransparency(1)
end)
if not  f=="SetTopbarTransparency is not a valid member of PlayerGui" then
    -- old topbar is present
else
    -- new topbar is present
end
```

It works, because with the new topbar `SetTopbarTransparency` is deprecated.